# PHP exec() not grabbing output from bash command

Tags: php, linux, bash

i'm trying to get the ouput from a bash command.
If I execute the some command directly in the bash, i see the result. But not with PHP exec() function..

```
$command = "ffmpeg -i '$video_path' 2>&1 | grep Video | perl -wle 'while(<>){ $_ =~ /.*?(\d+x\d+).*/; print $1; }'";
$res = exec($command/*, $output*/);

print_r($res);
// print_r($output);
```

This command try to get a video resolution using ffmpeg lib. The video path it's fine, I triple check that.

Thanks!

EDIT: screenshot from the output in bash

[image]

Comment: Per [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), "The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the `passthru()` function."

Comment: The easiest way to get the full output of a command into a string is to use backticks (`)

Comment: It looks like you have tried to use the output argument to exec, which will contain all of the output, rather than the last line. What is in $output when you run it that way?

Comment: The output has just one line, I add an screenshot in the question where you can check that.

Comment: Should I need to escape some of this chars? $_ =~ /.*?(\d+x\d+).*/; ?

Comment: @Rob Ruchte $output is just and empty array. I tried using passthru(), and $output now has "560" the first part of the result that should be 560x320 (resolution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the $ in your regex with a backslash. Since you're wrapping everything in double quotes, PHP is trying to insert the value of $_, which is not a thing. I got an undefined variable notice when I ran your code. It worked for me when I escaped the $.